# Python Filtering in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to retrieve a column values based on the value of another column.
something like
select col1 from table where col2 in ('x','y')

hostToBeCommissioned=df3.iloc[[:,0]& (df3['ACTION'].isin('OnBoard'))]

i trying to fetch all column 0 where column ACTION has value as OnBoard.
Pls let me know.

Comment: posting df.head() makes it a lot more easy to visualize what are you asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
df3.loc[df3['ACTION'].isin(['list of values']), 'col_you_want']
```

so i am guessing something like:

```
df3.loc[df3['ACTION'].isin(['OnBoard']), df.columns[0]]
```

Comment: np, mark as correctly answered if possible so it is a closed issue

Comment: i am getting  hostID = df1.loc[df1[Constants.HOST].isin([host]), df1.columns[3]] -> this returns me index value, how can i skip the index here..

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html    explains how to use the .loc function on a dataframe